# How do i call GAS Execution API's run method from container bound script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have made an target project script as instructed by google in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api) and followed all the steps for deploying as a API Executable.Enabled the Google apps script execution API also.

In documentation, they have mentioned a Execution API's [run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution/rest/v1/scripts/run) method. By using this we can call the projects method. i don't know how to use this in GAS.

This is the target project's script,

```
/**
 * The function in this script will be called by the Apps Script Execution API.
 */

/**
 * Return the set of folder names contained in the user's root folder as an
 * object (with folder IDs as keys).
 * @return {Object} A set of folder names keyed by folder ID.
 */
function getFoldersUnderRoot() {
  var root = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var folders = root.getFolders();
  var folderSet = {};
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    folderSet[folder.getId()] = folder.getName();
  }
  return folderSet;
}
```

I'd tried following method to call execution API's run method, but it required access token, how can i get the access token in this code.

```
var access_token=ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();//Returning a string value  
var url = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/MvwvW29XZxP77hsnIkgD0H88m6KuyrhZ5:run";
var headers = {
  "Authorization": "Bearer "+access_token,
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
};
var payload = {
  'function': 'getFoldersUnderRoot',
  devMode: true
};
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
  method: "post",
  headers: headers,
  payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
  muteHttpExceptions: true
});
```

But in response i'm getting this,

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "ScriptError",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.apps.script.v1.ExecutionError",
        "errorMessage": "Authorization is required to perform that action.",
        "errorType": "ScriptError"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How can i solve this? Code explanation would be appreciable. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this sample script? From your question, I could know that you have already done deploying API Executable and enabling Execution API. In order to use Execution API, also an access token with scopes you use is required as you can see at Requirements. Have you already retrieved it? If you don't have it yet, you can retrieve it by checking [the Auth Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). By preparing these, you can use Execution API.

Following sample is for run `getFoldersUnderRoot()` in the project deployed API Executable. Please copy and paste this sample script to your spreadsheet script editor. Before you use this, please import your access token and script ID of the project deployed API Executable to the script.

#### Sample script :

```
var url = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/### Script ID ###:run";
var headers = {
  "Authorization": "Bearer ### acces token ###",
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
};
var payload = {
  'function': 'getFoldersUnderRoot',
  devMode: true
};
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
  method: "post",
  headers: headers,
  payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
  muteHttpExceptions: true
});
```

#### Result :

Here, the result of `getFoldersUnderRoot()` is returned as follows.

```
{
  "done": true,
  "response": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.apps.script.v1.ExecutionResponse",
    "result": {
      "### folder id1 ### ": "### folder name1 ###",
      "### folder id2 ### ": "### folder name2 ###",
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can i simply use ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(); for getting access token ?

Comment: @Siddhesh Mishra For this situation, the access token cannot be retrieved using ``ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()``. Because ``https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts`` is not included in the scop using ``ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()``. If you want to retrieve the access token with scopes you set using Google Apps Script, you can use this sample. https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/247e4db66098e94f9e7da1b857f0a9be

Comment: I saw your github's code, but i have doubt about how would it work here in GAS, as you had deployed your script as a WEB APPS and in my case i had done it as OTHER. So what would be theredirectUri here ?

Comment: @Siddhesh Mishra I'm sorry. I noticed that my sample is not enough for the information. So I updated it. Please confirm again.

Comment: it would be great to be in touch with you as i'm beginning to learn google apps script. So can you give me a mail id or any other source to be get connected with you. Thank you.

Comment: @Siddhesh Mishra Although you can see my e-mail address from GitHub of my profile, if you have problems about your this question, please post them here. Other SO users can know the solution of your question. At first, will you solve your question?

Comment: No i wouldn't, just check the updated question, and i don't want to deploy it as a Web App, i have deployed it as a OTHER option.In this case what would be the solution?

Comment: @Siddhesh Mishra No problem. In such case, my sample cannot be used. So please retrieve access token by reading [the Auth Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). In generally, a lot of users retrieves the access token by checking the guide.

Comment: No probelm, your inputs bring the problem to the last phase, Thanks.